# I can't track down the possible copy construction bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory

I have an issue where **some members** of a class, from one pointer, are identical (as they should be) but from another pointer they are different. This *probably* means a copy construction took place somewhere, but I'm not sure/ **I can't find it**.  I already added an error/break point in what would be the copy construction routine (previously undefined)

```
class Foo
{
    Foo( const Foo& foo )
    {
        error( "Copying a foo: not allowed" ) ;
    }
};
```

The break point never gets hit.

I'm using VS 2010.  How can I track this bug?

Comment: It doesn't give you a stack trace when you reach that break point?

Comment: Make `Foo(const Foo&)` private so you'll get a compile error.

Comment: I amn't sure why you came to conclusion that copy construction is the culprit. Please post some more helpful code.

Comment: Well I can't post more code without the question becoming too long. I'm _not_ sure copy construction is the culprit, I'm kind of assuming so.

Comment: What do you mean?  I don't think there's a rule about how long your question can be.  Post more code.

Comment: Don't you mean __moar__ code?  I think I found the problem, which is why making `Foo(const Foo&)` private didn't work - I was doing `(*this) = *newObj ;`.. details below.

Comment: @bobobobo: that would be the assignment operator that's causing you problems, not the copy constructor.

Comment: Yes. For some reason I thought this automatically invoked the copy ctor! But it turns out [copy constructor initializes uninitialized memory, whereas assignment starts with an existing initialized object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163742.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To make your classes non-copyable I suggest you use `boost::noncopyable` to make them so, and then you'll be sure that copy construction won't be allowed.  If it does accidentally happen, your compiler will tell you somethings up.

Comment: That's `boost::noncopyable`, no underscore.